# call to 'approve' entrypoint of tzBTC contract failing with 'UnsafeAllowanceChange'

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, contract, fa1.2

I'm trying to call `addLiquidity` on the Liquidity Baking CPMM. I've already called `xtzToToken` on the CPMM and given my address tzBTC. I can see that [my address](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot/operations/) has tokens on the [tzBTC contract when I look at that contracts storage](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN/storage/0). The CPMM tells me I have 300000004 tokens I believe.

[My address also has allowances declared on the tzBTC contract that allow the CPMM to spend it's tokens.](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN/storage/1), the allowance is only 10 and when I try to chance it I get an `UnsafeAllowanceChange` error.

I want to make my allowance something super high that I don't have to worry about reaching the allowance when I call `addLiquidity`. How can I get past this error?

Here is what I'm trying to run:

```
# call approve on the tzBTC contract
tezos-client transfer 0 from alice to KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN \
                        --entrypoint approve \
                        --arg '(Pair "KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN" 99954268)'  \
                        --burn-cap 999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the allowance is only 10 and when I try to chance it I get an `UnsafeAllowanceChange` error.

This error is raised because the allowance is already `10`, from the [`UnsafeAllowanceChange` documentation](https://github.com/tz-wrapped/tezos-btc/blob/autodoc/master/TZBTC-contract.md#errors-UnsafeAllowanceChange):

> **Fires if**: Allowance change from non-zero value to non-zero value is performed. This contract does not allow such an update, see the [corresponding attack vector](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YLPtQxZu1UAvO9cZ1O2RPXBbT0mooh4DYKjA_jp-RLM) for explanation.

See the section #3 of the linked document for an example/scenario explanation.

> I want to make my allowance something super high that I don't have to worry about reaching the allowance when I call addLiquidity. How can I get past this error?

The [`approve` documentation](https://github.com/tz-wrapped/tezos-btc/blob/autodoc/master/TZBTC-contract.md#approve) explains why it's prohibited and how to perform this change safely:

> It is not safe to change the approval from a non-zero value to a non-zero value.
> This is the reason why performing such a change directly is not allowed by the contract.
> However this is not enough on its own, a token holder that intends to
> safely change the allowance for `X` to `K` token must:
>
> 1. read the current allowance `M` for `X` from the latest transaction `S`.
> 2. send a transaction `T` that sets the allowance to `0`.
> 3. wait for the blockchain to confirm that `T` is included.
> 4. scan all transactions between `S` and `T`.
> 5. calculate the allowance `N <= M` spent by `X` in those transactions.
> 6. set the allowance to `K - N` iff `N < K`.

In other words, the allowance needs to be set from `10` to `0` first and then from `0` to the new value, accounting for allowance uses that may have happened in the meanwhile.

Comment: Thank you for linking to the official docs. I tried reading three Michaelson and the docs of the CPMM and couldn't find it, I didn't even realize it could be passed back from the tzBTC contact.

Comment: No problem, I see how that could be confusing.